# how to display data in table using handlebarsjs

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I am creating my first emberjs project and for template engine I am using handlebarsjs , I am getting data from server using ajax call in this format:

```
{"data":[{"ownerName":"dubey","houseNo":"s17/261","streetName":"chinchwad","areaName":"thergaon","city":"pune","pinZip":"221003","stateProvince":"maharastra","country":"india","shaded":"yes","lat":null,"lon":null,"rate":"29","status":"open","availibility":"open","contactNo":null,"id":"589704c2a924113eb8841952"},{"ownerName":"dubey","houseNo":"s17/261","streetName":"chinchwad","areaName":"thergaon","city":"pune","pinZip":"221003","stateProvince":"maharastra","country":"india","shaded":"yes","lat":null,"lon":null,"rate":"29","status":"open","availibility":"open","contactNo":null,"id":"58971125df1e11416e91ccc3"}]}
```

and my template is :

```
<tbody>
      {{#each data.data}}
    <tr>
      <th>{{data.data.[0].houseNo}}</th>
      <th>{{data.data.[0].houseNo}}</th>
      <th>{{data.data.[0].streetName}}</th>
      <th>{{data.data.[0].areaName}}</th>
      <th>{{data.data.[0].city}}</th>
      <th>{{data.data.[0].pinZip}}</th>
      <th>{{data.data.[0].stateProvince}}</th>
      <th>{{data.data.[0].country}}</th>
      <th>{{data.data.[0].shaded}}</th>
      <th>{{data.data.[0].rate}}</th>
      <th>{{data.data.[0].status}}</th>
      <th>{{data.data.[0].availibility}}</th>
      <th>{{data.data.[0].ownerName}}</th>
      <th>{{data.data.[0].contactNo}}</th>
    </tr>
    {{/each}}
  </tbody>
```

it is showing only the first data in all the rows, I tried many ways to display all the data but I am not able to display it.

I want to know the handlebars way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data contains array of object so use `each` helper. if you want to iterate object then use [each-in helper](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#method_each-in).

```
{{#each  data.data as |row|}}
 {{each-in row as |key value|}}
<tr>
      <th>{{value}}</th>
</tr>
 {{/each-in}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html  - It contains all the supported template helpers. from guide https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.6.0/templates/displaying-a-list-of-items/

Answer (score 0):

By using `data.data.[0]`, you are always retrieving the first object.

Update your code to following

```
   {{#each data.data}}
    <tr>
      <th>{{houseNo}}</th>
      <th>{{houseNo}}</th>
      <th>{{streetName}}</th>
      <th>{{areaName}}</th>
      <th>{{city}}</th>
      <th>{{pinZip}}</th>
      <th>{{stateProvince}}</th>
      <th>{{country}}</th>
      <th>{{shaded}}</th>
      <th>{{rate}}</th>
      <th>{{status}}</th>
      <th>{{availibility}}</th>
      <th>{{ownerName}}</th>
      <th>{{contactNo}}</th>
    </tr>
  {{/each}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want additional functionalities like sorting, pagination, filter etc. along with the table then you can use ember models table,

https://github.com/onechiporenko/ember-models-table

You can find the demo here,

http://onechiporenko.github.io/ember-models-table/